# Simplicial set of permutations

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, gt.geometric-topology, simplicial-stuff, permutations

Let $S_k$ be  the set of all permutations of $k+1$ elements $0,1,...,k$. introduce boundary maps $d_i : S_k \rightarrow  S_{k-1}$ by deleting from permutation $\eta$ element $\eta(i)$ and monotone reordering and degeneracy
$s_i :S_k \rightarrow S_{k+1} $ by adding 1 to all elements with $\eta(j)>\eta(i)$  and incerting into the result a new element $\eta(i)+1$ right after $\eta(i)$ on $i+1$ place. It is a simplicial set, contractible and classifies reorderings of simplicial sets.

Is it known? May be in higher symmetric something?

(Update) Boris Tsygan pointed the right direction in [Facebook duscussion](https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=10157493966588914&id=811018913)

The object is classical and it has a name 
"Symmetric crossed simplicial group”.
It was introduced almost simultaneously 
in

Appendix A10, page 191
“Symmetric objects” 
B. L. Feigin and B. L. Tsygan
 “Additive K-theory”
 1987
 K-theory, arithmetic and geometry, Semin., Moscow Univ. 1984-86
LNM 1289

Krasauskas, R.
"Skew-simplicial groups",
Lithuanian Mathematical Journal,
Jan 1987
vol 27 issue 1
p. 47--54

And independently

Zbigniew Fiedorowicz and Jean-Louis Loday “Crossed simplicial groups and their associated homology”
Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 326 (1991), 57-87

It has big value in everything symmetric. Geometric realization $|S_\bullet|$ is the  topological group structure on infinite dimensional sphere.

Comment: In $s_i$ you mean that we insert something like $\eta(i)+1/2$? $\eta(i)+1$ may be already in the permutation.

Comment: $s_3(51243)=612354$, right?

Comment: @FedorPetrov right. Sorry was fighting with phone replying. Snd finnsly killed the comment.

Comment: @NikolaiMnev: If it's $\eta(i)+1$, then what about Fedor's comment? There is no canonical monotone reordering when two entries are equal.

Comment: @darijgrinberg  I am using  usual simplicial  topology conventions, attributing to simplicial degeneracy operation but permuted.  Meaning add one to all elements on j places with $\eta(j) > \eta(i)$ and  put as $i+1$-th element $\eta(i)+1$. it is right the same what Fedor says , but in simplicial algebra $\frac{1}{2}$ looks very foreign :)

Comment: Well, you omitted the "add 1" part in the OP.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Edited. There goes  fruitful discussion on Facebook, but i have no idea how to make a reference here.

Comment: @NikolaiMnev : Not everyone on MathOverflow is on Facebook. (I am not on Facebook.) I would recommend that you summarize the conclusions of the Facebook discussion here, either by editing your question or by posting an answer to your own question.

Comment: @TimothyChow Updated.

Comment: Facebook discussion?! What's this world coming to?

Comment: @AndrejBauer If you maintain a good friend list than a good discussion can be even on Facebook

Comment: @NikolaiMnev: I could never manage that, Facebook actively tries to impose things that are not "good discussion". I stopped using it a year ago, never looked back.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Sure, mr. Zuckerberg manipulates. But we can manipulate back :) But for the big international network of friends it is still the only place.

Answer (score 3):

I think something equivalent (or at least closely related) to this has been studied in the combinatorics literature.

A CW complex of course has a poset of faces.  In this case, this poset is obtained by ordering permutations by subword inclusion up to deletion and monotone reordering.  The keyword used in the combinatorics literature for this sort of subword inclusion is *permutation patterns*.

Now, if a CW complex is regular, then the order complex of the face poset is homeomorphic to the complex.  As you point out in the comments, the simplicial set has $n!$ faces of dimension $n$, and in particular has a single vertex.  So the simplicial set isn't regular, as I'd initially thought it might be, and your question doesn't reduce directly to this poset.  It certainly seems like the two objects should be closely related, however.

In any case, the lattice of permutations ordered by pattern containment has been studied by Jason Smith.  See, for example, the paper

*Smith, Jason P.*, [**A formula for the Möbius function of the permutation poset based on a topological decomposition**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.aam.2017.06.002), Adv. Appl. Math. 91, 98-114 (2017). [ZBL1370.05227](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1370.05227).

That paper cites also his earlier papers on the topic.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. It is certainly related to permutation patterns.  I can simply count nodegenerate simples here as something like subfactorial, for example, using pattern views. But itself it is very  very far from regular  complex. it has a single  vertex two adges and factorials of other simplexes  glued on this tiny 8. may be it is glued from some classic regular complexes in an interesting singular way. Itbwold be cool to know. thank you for the reference!

Comment: Yes, I should've caught the one vertex thing.  Edited to better reflect.  I'm not familiar enough with the simplicial set way of thinking to know if there's some other well-travelled path between the two objects.

Comment: @RussWoodfore  Geometric realization of this thing  looks strange in finite parts but actually an infinite dimensional Lie group  as a whole thing. Wonders of simplicial topology. I still surprised